# Why I can't get the correct value from api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I have tried to post data in postman and it returns a json object , the methods are working good . 
I have a problem to get the value of attribut when the api respond with a json object .
the forma of json like this :

```
{
 "success" : "true"
}
```

the api method :

```
router.post("/sickers/user/login/", (req, res) => {
    var values = JSON.parse(req.body);
    var pass = values.password;
    var email = values.email;
    //console.log(values);
    if (pass !== null || pass !== "") {
        try {
            con.connect();
            con.query("SELECT Password FROM `sickers` WHERE Email='" + email + "'", function(err, rows, field) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send("an error detected try later");
                } else {
                    try {
                        if (pass == rows[0].Password) {

                            //trying to send correct message from here
                            res.send({ success: "true" });
                            console.log("yes")
                        } else {

                            console.log("no")
                            res.send({ success: "false" });
                        }
                    } catch {

                        console.log("no")
                        res.send({ success: "false" });
                    }

                }
            });
        } catch (e) {

            res.send("no data found");
            console.log("obj not found");
        }
    }
con.end();
});
```

the post method from a react app is :

```
//submit values
async submithandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   try{
   await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/sickers/user/login/',{
     method:'post',
     mode:'no-cors',
     headers:{
         'Accept':'application/json',
         'Content-type': 'application/json'
     },
     body:JSON.stringify({
           password:this.state.password,
           email:this.state.email
     })
    })
    .then(response=>{
        this.setState({data:response})
        alert(data.success);
    })

    }catch(e){
        alert(e)
    }

}
```

the data declaration in state : data:[]
the error is that the data is undefined .

Comment: Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) `.then(response => response.json()).then(data => ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Fetch API to Access JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663674/using-fetch-api-to-access-json)

Comment: thanks for reply , the method you mention is true and works , but I have problem with `response.json()` it shows me **Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input** every time I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is two problems here at this example with both parts api and react app , 
the first thing I did is to understand cors and how it works in express and I found that I should do the following steps to the api :

run

```
npm install cors
```

second is to add

```
const cors =require('cors')
```

and then :

```
app.use(cors());
```

and last step is inside the router post I should add cors :

```
router.post('path',cors(),(req,res)....
```

about react app code it just need to remove `module="no-cors"`

and then it works .

Answer (score 0):

when you do an api call using **fetch** request, it returns a **promise** that contains the **response** and that **response** is resolved by the first **.then()**. after resolving this **first promise** it returns another **response** and you need to resolve it with another **.then()**

Please check the working example below:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class FetchExample extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isLoading: false,
        questions: [],
        error: null
    };

    fetchQuestions = () => {
        fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&difficulty=hard&type=boolean`,)
            .then(response => {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        console.log('There was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);
                        return;
                    }
                    response.json().then(data => {
                        console.log(data);
                        this.setState({
                            questions: data,
                            isLoading: false
                        })
                    });
                }
            )
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ', error);
                this.setState({error, isLoading: false})
            });
    };

    render() {
        const {isLoading, questions, error} = this.state;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Random Question</h1>
                <button onClick={this.fetchQuestions}>Click for calling API using fetch</button>
                {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}

                {!isLoading && questions.results ? (
                    questions.results.map((questions, index) => {    //something right here
                        //is erroring
                        const {question, category, type, difficulty} = questions;
                        return (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <p>Question: {question}</p>
                                <p>Question Type: {type}</p>
                                <p>Difficulty: {difficulty}</p>
                                <hr/>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                ) : isLoading ? (
                    <h3>Loading...</h3>
                ) : null}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default FetchExample;
```

Comment: thanks for reply , the method you mention is true and works , but I have problem with `response.json()` it shows me **Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input**

Comment: @AzizMobarak, pls remove `mode: 'no-cors' ` for more detail please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-when-using-mode-no-cors/43319482#43319482

Comment: I got ` TypeError: Failed to fetch` when removing no-cors , note that I m using POST method and I want to get response values and not get. thanks.