# Fetching local JSON object with React.js problem, Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

So i want to fetch from my local data.js file. It looks like this:

```
{
  product_name: [
  {'name': 'hello',
   'lastName': 'hello'
   }, {'name': 'hi',
   'lastName': 'hi'}
]
}
```

Is this valid JSON?
My code that I'm fetching it with looks like this :

```
fetch('./data.json')
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(text=> console.log(text))
```

After this, I get an error in my console.log. Also when I go to the network tab and click on data.json It tells me that javascript needs to be enabled, what does that mean? Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to solve your answer.

## First things

You must remember to format the JSON so that it is readable by a user, if you are currently developing your program. In production mode, you can skip this step, but it is a good practice.

Next, **The JSON you have does not seem to use quotes for keys. This is a must for JSON.**
If you don't like the quotes, use [json5](https://json5.org/), JSON's friendlier brother.

## Next,

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37664029/14925444) explains about JSON with `fetch`.

> The Fetch API returns a response stream in the promise. The response stream is not JSON, so trying to call JSON.parse on it will fail. To correctly parse a JSON response, you'll need to use the response.json function. This returns a promise so you can continue the chain.

I see that you have done it, but are forgetting the `GET` method mentioned in the above post. And, use `return` keyword to pass the JSON to the next promise. So, your corrected JS code will be:

```js
fetch('./data.json', { method: "GET" })
        .then(res => return res.json())
        .then(text => console.log(text))
```

I am not an expert in React, but these are some common things I can correct.

## 2nd Part of Question

I do not really know why it says JavaScript needs to be enabled. Maybe go to your settings and enable JavaScript? Or, if you use an ad-blocker, try disabling it once and see.

## Final Words

I think I have solved a part of your question.